# send data from python to cordova app via Bluetooth

Tags: android, python, cordova, bluetooth, phonegap

Hello to All Developers,

I am facing problem to make communication channel between Python to cordova (Phonegap) App.

I have an python script that is sending data it is working only when I receive data by another python script via bluetooth.

But I couldn't any solution to receive data in cordova app.

This is python script.

```
import bluetooth

bd_addr = "01:23:45:67:89:AB"

port = 1

sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((bd_addr, port))

sock.send("hello!!")

sock.close()
```

I want to make an cordova script that will receive data in android phone.

It will be more appreciate if I got help from you side.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

If you want to use sockets to connect and transfer data you could try this plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-networking-bluetooth

Installation:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin
```

Example connection:

```
var uuid = '94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee';

networking.bluetooth.connect(device.address, uuid, function (socketId) {
    // Profile implementation here. 
}, function (errorMessage) {
    console.log('Connection failed: ' + errorMessage);
});
```

Example receiving data from a socket:

```
networking.bluetooth.onReceive.addListener(function (receiveInfo) {
      if (receiveInfo.socketId !== socketId) {
          return;
      }

      // receiveInfo.data is an ArrayBuffer. 
});
```

**Original**

I have used this plugin before:

https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

Installation:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial
```

Your phone must initiate the connection though, then you can use the subscribe method to listen for data. This data is then passed to the callback function.

In your data sent from the python script you will need to include a delimiter such as a new line so that the plugin knows when it has finished reading the data. Usage is like this:

```
function connectSuccess(){

    //The first argument is the delimiter to stop reading data at

    bluetoothSerial.subscribe('\n', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, failure);

}

function failure(e){

    console.log('Subscribe failure: ' + e);

}

function connectFailure(e){

    console.log('Connect failure: ' + e);

}

bluetoothSerial.connect(macAddress_or_uuid, connectSuccess, connectFailure);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying your way, please keep in touch.

Comment: Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: Yes I tried but after connect api it give error Unable to connect.

Comment: anyone is there who can help me??

Comment: bluetoothSerial.connect(
                app.macAddress, // device to connect to
                app.openPort, // start listening if you succeed
                app.showError // show the error if you fail
            );

its showing error Unable to connect to device

Comment: Try using bluetoothSerial.connectInsecure instead.

Comment: Yes It may be fix my problem let me trying it

Comment: I got the connection between mobile and python server but I want to receive data on App.
do you know about any bluetooth socket server in cordova

Comment: I want something cordova bluetooth socket server that receive data sent by python script

Comment: I don't understand both the methods in my answer will receive data just fine?

Comment: Connection is establish and I can send data from app to my python script, But I need to revert this, I want to receive data on android app.
I think I need bluetooth rfcomm socket server in cordova do you know any plugin that provide feature of bluetooth rfcomm socket server.

Comment: The plugin I I referenced in my edit will do what you need. Just be sure the read the documentation.